# Generate content code from Icon s pack - CSS

Tags: css, svg, icons

I have downloaded a simple template from the internet and for icons, the developer used Flaticons font. Now I want to put another icon on the website but I can't get Flaticons code for CSS file. On [Flaticon site](https://www.flaticon.com/) only can be downloaded in PSD, SVG, BASE 64 I don't have code like `.flaticon-research:before { content: "\f100"; }`. How to get that? Is there any solution to convert SVG file to get that content or how? I don't want to download every single SVG file and from the SVG file get the icon. I want to use the above example method. Any help will be welcome. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

follow the instruction here https://www.flaticon.com/iconfonts

after downloading the font you will see multiple files show you how to use your icons depending on you using  `css` or `scss`

Comment: You show me how to do that and my question is totally different. I don't need to add another font in the root of my website I need to add new icons from the same font.

Comment: Ah this is interesting, I updated my answer hope to be what you are looking for

Comment: They don't have that option from their following steps. I looked up and I didn't find that. Only if they allow that from a premium account.

Comment: I tested it without  premium account and it works ... just add free icons and then click the green download btn and choose icon font btn ...

Comment: Can you ss to me... I'm blind -.-

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TYP3s9o_UL9OFcTLfAcm6Pxfcy-ttttO/view?usp=sharing